# How to use javascript to achieve scroll loading, the mouse can automatically scroll to the bottom to display the newly loaded content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to realize that when scrolling to the bottom of the window, more information can be loaded in, so far it has been done! But I have two problems: 1. I don't know how to make the scroll scroll to the bottom to see the newly loaded data when the data is loaded? 2. Since I will trigger a loading function when I scroll to the bottom, if it will automatically scroll to the bottom when the data is loaded, this will not trigger the loading function. What I want is to only load each time I scroll Enter four data. I have tried many ways and still don't know how to solve the above two problems I encountered, I hope to get your help, thank you very much.

```js
let str = ""
let limit = 4;
let offset = 0;

let data = [{
    id: 5,
    title: "title5"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "title6"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "title7"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "title8"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: "title9"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    title: "title10"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    title: "title11"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    title: "title12"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    title: "title13"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    title: "title14"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    title: "title15"
  }
];

function addData() {
  let newData = data.splice(0, limit);
  if (newData.length === 0) return;

  str = "";
  newData.forEach(e => {
    str += `  <li class="message">
      <div class='id'>${e.id}</div>
      <div>${e.title}</div>
    </li>`
  });
  content.innerHTML += str;
}

let loading = false;
let content = document.querySelector('.content');
content.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (loading || data.length === 0) return;

  if (content.scrollTop + content.clientHeight >= content.scrollHeight) {
    loading = true;
    document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
      addData();
      document.querySelector('.loading').style.display = 'none';
      loading = false;
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.id {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.loading {
  display: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu3XilJ5BOiSGic/giphy.gif');
}
```

```html
<ul class="content">
  <li class="message">
    <div class='id'>1</div>
    <div>title1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="message">
    <div class='id'>2</div>
    <div>title2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="message">
    <div class='id'>3</div>
    <div>title3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="message">
    <div class='id'>4</div>
    <div>title4</div>
  </li>
  <div class="loading"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you look up some tutorials of Infinite Scroll?